# Where in MediaWiki is the code for links to user pages?

Tags: mediawiki

On my site, I would like to change the code so that whenever a user's page is linked, (in the personal links in the upper right, after recent changes, anywhere really), instead of navigating to a user's page on the wiki, it directs to another completely separate page. The link itself I have worked out. I just need to find exactly what I need to edit in the MediaWiki code.

Similarly, I'd like to know where the code is for displaying links to talk pages as well.

Comment: At first I tried looking the vector theme, but then I realized it's more likely to be in some .php file in the general mediawiki folders. I really have no idea where to start looking.

Answer (score 1):

You should [not hack the MediaWiki core](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Do_not_hack_MediaWiki_core) for this. It will make your wiki difficult or impossible to maintain and keep updated.

What you are probably looking for is a [hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks), that lets you [write an extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Developing_extensions) to modify the behaviour of some internal links. Your best shot is probably [`InternalParseBeforeLinks`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/InternalParseBeforeLinks) or [`InternalParseBeforeSanitize`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/InternalParseBeforeSanitize). This will, of course, not prevent anyone from visiting the user pages and talk pages, but it will change the behaviour of internal links.

For a very simple example of an extension using this hook see e.g. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TernaryPipedLinks

To change the behaviour of links in the wiki's header, etc, you will have to write your own custom skin, or modify an existing one. That is a much larger task. And users will still be able to visit the said pages, of course.

edit: The suggestion from svick in the comments would probably make a lot more sense, in your case

Comment: Wouldn't automatic redirect (HTTP redirect, not MediaWiki redirect) from all `User:` pages make more sense?

Comment: @Kvick Yes, that's probably a much better solution. D'oh